# How to get selectionStart and selectionEnd properties of v-textarea in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I know you can get the startSelection and selectionEnd properties of normal `<textarea>` by using DOM or $refs in VueJS.

I however am struggling to accomplish the same thing with `<v-textarea>`. I have googled around and most things either use normal JS with `<textarea>` or VueJS but also with `<textarea>`.

Sample Code:

```js
 <v-textarea
            :value="value"
            :label="label"
            hide-details="auto"
            :name="name"
            auto-grow
            no-resize
            clearable
            rows="1"
            @input="emitSelectedPositons"
            :error-messages="errorMessages"
            ref="vta"
/>

...

<script>
  ....
  methods: {
      emitSelectedPositons() {
          this.$emit('changed', {
              start: this.$refs.vta.selectionStart,
              end: this.$refs.vta.selectionEnd
          })
      }
  }
</script>
```

The code above returns `undefined` for both.

Comment: Could you check if [issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5081) helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$refs.vta` only returns the v-textarea element, which is a wrapper element containing its own refs which includes the inner `<textarea>` input element. You can access the inner element to get selectionStart and selectionEnd like so:

```js
this.start = this.$refs.vta.$refs.input.selectionStart;
this.end = this.$refs.vta.$refs.input.selectionEnd;
```

[sandbox example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/LYBbgOX?editors=1011)

Comment: This worked, thank you. It is a bit disappointing that the properties will have to get accessed through another ref instead of being on the component level already

Answer (score 1):

With the Vuetify upgrade to **Vuetify 3**, `this.$refs.vta.$refs.input.selectionStart` no longer works.

Here's how to access selectionStart for a v-textarea

```
this.$refs.vta.$el.querySelector('textarea').selectionStart
```